# Rendering an image from Amazon S3 on VF page

Tags: apex, amazon, aws

Iam using Amazon toolkit to integrate SF with Amazon S3.

I want to render the content(image) of files in a bucket when bucket is selected from a selectlist. 
Like ListBucket, I am calling a method `getObject'`which in turn calls the webservice operation `GetObject`
from the S3 class. 
I can see the request and response(200) in my developer console but there is an exception:

**ERROR: Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element Status**.[image]

Can someone help me to resolve this please.?

[EDIT]

This is The method which is in controller which further makes a call to a method of S3 class which performs a web service callout.

### -

-
public PageReference GetObject()
    {
         try{   Datetime now = Datetime.now();
            String Delimiter = null;
            Boolean  GetMetadata  =true;
            Boolean  GetData=true;
            Boolean  InlineData=true;
            System.debug('GetObject for bucket: ' + bucketToList);

//This performs the Web Service call to Amazon S3 and retrieves all the objects in the specified bucket

```
        S3.GetObjectResult response = as3.GetObject(bucketToList,'demo4'   ,GetMetadata,GetData,InlineData,as3.key,now,as3.signature('GetObject',now),as3.secret);

        return null;
     }
        catch(Exception ex){
        System.debug('EXCEPTION: ' + ex);
        getobjectErrorMsg =    ex.getMessage();
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        return null; 

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a similar case . Anybody having solution to this can please guide .

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Amazon toolkit specifically, however I imagine it would be something to do with it trying to deserialize the XML response into an Apex class that is missing a property called "Status". If you are able to provide the line of code that is making the callout that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Ok , so I have resolved the error above after following the link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008xNYIAY

where I needed to Change GetObjectResult orginal code to also get 'status' and  'field_order'.

Now I have the issue of rendering the image content on page . I have the response string(image content) .

```
<apex:image value="data:image;base64,{!imagecontent}" />
```

The cntroller has getObject() with  following code snippet

```
   S3.GetObjectResult response = as3.GetObject(bucketToList,'demo41' ,GetMetadata,GetData,InlineData,as3.key,now,as3.signature('GetObject',now),as3.secret);
  String imagecontent = response.data;
```

Is it the right way to go?

Comment: I presume that response.data is indeed in base64 form? Provided that it is then yes this shouldn't be a problem, although you may need to specify the image type e.g. "data:image/png,base64,". You could inspect the src attribute of the rendered image tag in your page to confirm.

Comment: Specifying `value="data:image;base64,{!imageContent}"` seems like the right approach, as long as your content is indeed Base64-encoded: http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: Hi, Yes My content is in Base64-encoded format as I have checked by specifying 
`<apex:image value="data:image;base64,9j/weds/wdddewdsdfaffd......" />`


But still I cant see the image in VF page . I need to get the image from controller to VF page and not as hardcoded.

Comment: Hi friends, now it is working , I think I was placing the <apex image> tag at wrong place in VF page.
Thank you so much for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter your [root account credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/getting-aws-sec-creds.html) into the **AWS Credentials** record you're using with the Force.com for Amazon Web Services app? The package was created a long time ago, probably before Amazon.com introduced the IAM feature.

I just [installed the package](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Installing_Force_for_Amazon_Web_Services) in my DE org. I confirmed that while I cannot use an IAM account with the **S3 Samples** tab, the tab works with my root credentials. You can see the tab working as expected in the screenshot below.

[image: S3 Samples tab]

Comment: Hi @Marty-c , Yes I have correctly added the credentials. Also the whole thing is working correctly as in your case. There are some commented out methods of S3 class which I am trying to implement 'getObject'. withthis I want to render the contents (file- image/jpeg) in my VF page and doing this created this error above.

Comment: I tried to use IAM user credentials with salesforce package and its giving error. But when I used root user credentials with salesforce package, its working fine. So I agree with Marty that IAM thing doesnt work with salesforce package. Does salesforce plan to uprgrade the package to support IAM creds too ?